# How to plot 0 or 1 values on one row in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a dataset on blood culture results in different timepoints. The results are either positive, negative or missing. I would like to vaisualize the results one line as, positive results by filled square/circle and the negative results with un-filled square/circle.

I have used the following code to convert char to numeric values:

```
Blood_cul: record_id     value    time_since_challenge
              1         Positive       25

Blood_cul$value[ Blood_cul$value == "0" ] <- NA

Blood_cul <- Blood_cul %>% 
  mutate(value = recode(value, 
                        "NG5" = "0", 
                        "Positive" = "1"
  ))  
Blood_cul<-within(Blood_cul, value <- factor(value, labels = c(0, 1)))
```

Using ggplot,

```
ggplot(Blood_cul, aes(x=time_since_challenge, y=value, group=1))+geom_point()
```

I get the points in two rows of zero and 1.

Can anyone help me how to have the plot on one row and add it to my other plots for the temprature? I am thinking of having a row in the bottom of my temprature plot for the blood culture.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to do? Should the points be on 1 line? Are they not filled correctly? The problem seems to be the plotting itself rather than the recording, so it might be helpful to show expected output for a small example like `time_since_challenge <- 1:10; set.seed(1); value = rbinom(10, 1, .5)`. For a base plot, you could manualle plot them using `points` twice with appriate `x` and `y` values, using `pch` to choose the proper fill.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. In your example the points appear in (time,0) and (time,1) coordinates. What I want is to have all the points on (time,0) coordinate, but the values=1 with filled square and values=0 with empty square.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a heatmap where the fill is determined by the value, you can add an artificial y axis with one value for all your data points.

`ggplot(Blood_cul, aes(x=time_since_challenge, fill=value, y=y))+geom_tile(color = "black") + scale_fill_gradient(high = "black", low = "white") + theme_minimal()`